# Using Bluetooth to RECEIVE file - From Mobile to PC

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, silverlight, bluetooth

I took me several time and days to research and try some codes applicable to my problem but unfortunately I wasn't able to see codes that pair and **receive** files (text, images etc..NOT audio or video in particular) from a mobile device.

Most of the examples found are for **SENDING** only (From PC to Mobile).

I have bluetooth device (USB) physically attached to my PC.

**Summary:**

All I need is a sample code that automatically detect/pair when a device is trying to send the file (like in Kodak kiosk but not limited to images only).

I also wanted to understand and study the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps use my [32feet.NET](http://32feet.codeplex.com) library and its ObexListener class see e.g. http://32feet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Server-side&referringTitle=OBEX

For more advanced scenarios use Andy Hume's Brecham.Obex library and his server sample application.  See http://inthehand.co.uk/files/folders/objectexchange/entry9942.aspx

Which Bluetooth stack does your PC have installed?  Microsoft, Widcomm, BlueSoleil...?  See e.g. http://32feet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Supported%20Hardware%20and%20Software  On Widcomm for instance the build-in OBEX server would have to be disabled to allow your server to get all the incoming connections...

Comment: @alanmcf I've been through all of your suggestions including most of the documenation of 32feet.Net. I'm just wondering if Windows 64bit PC is supported? because I tried some example that supposed to run using 32feet.Net lib..ObexListener etc.. BUT in my case, nothing happened. I still need to manually right click my bluetooth icon device and select 'Receive File'..

Comment: Works for me...  Win7 x64, Microsoft Bluetooth stack.  What's the value of `BluetoothRadio.PrimaryRadio.SoftwareManufacturer`?  "Nothing happened"?  No error on sender?